# Evaluation error (NoSuchMethodError) in Azure ApplicationTokenCredentials when trying to start a VM

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM that I need to remotely control. I'm authenticating using ApplicationTokenCredentials in the expected way;

`ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(client,
        tenant,
        key,
        AzureEnvironment.AZURE);`

Then finding my machine:

`VirtualMachine vm = Azure
        .configure()
        .withLogLevel(LogLevel.NONE)
        .authenticate(credentials)
        .withSubscription(subscription)
        .virtualMachines()
        .getByResourceGroup(resourceGroup, machineName);`

This is essentially the same approach as the official documentation here shows;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/java-sdk-manage-virtual-machines?view=azure-java-stable

This works, authenticates, and sets me up with a VirtualMachine object. I've confirmed that that's what it is and that it's the correct machine that I'm looking to control.

However when I try to start it with the start() method, this happens:

```
Evaluation error (NoSuchMethodError) at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials.getToken (ApplicationTokenCredentials.java:138).
```

My dependency tree looks fine. I'm using the newest version (1.35.0) of com.microsoft.azure (and only that) from maven central;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
        <version>1.35.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Of course this is the parent dependency and it pulls down a bunch of artifacts. My dependency tree seems fine at a glance though:

```
+- com.microsoft.azure:azure:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-client-runtime:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.microsoft.rest:client-runtime:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.12.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging- 
interceptor:jar:3.12.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp- 
urlconnection:jar:3.12.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter- 
jackson:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson- 
databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype- 
joda:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson- 
annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-client- 
authentication:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.microsoft.azure:azure-annotations:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-resources:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-storage:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-network:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-graph-rbac:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-keyvault:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-batch:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt- 
trafficmanager:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-dns:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-redis:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-appservice:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-locks:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-eventhub:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-cdn:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-sql:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-         
containerinstance:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-         
containerregistry:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt- 
containerservice:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-cosmosdb:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-search:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-msi:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-monitor:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-servicebus:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-batchai:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mgmt-compute:jar:1.35.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
```

At least I don't see anything that stands out as dependency conflict here. I really have no idea how to proceed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting up a test project with just the VM management and found that working on the same dependencies.

After painstakingly comparing the dependencies between the two, I found one discrepancy; the version of the com.microsoft.azure.adal4j package was 1.6.4 on my test project, and 1.0.0 on my production app.

I have no idea how my production app ended up with an older version of this since all the root azure dependencies are identical, but I added this dependency to my production app, which fixed the issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```